# How to list the vehicle based on selected faculty

Tags: php

i have a list box to show the list of vehicle when user select the faculty. i want to list only the vehicle based on the selected faculty by user.

```
<td>No</td>
<td>Registration No</td>

<?php
     $count = 0;
     $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') 
     or die ("unable to connect");

 mysql_select_db('fyp',$db) or die ("able to select");
 $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle_record";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query failed!");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $count = $count + 1;
?>

<select name="faculty" >
               <option value="" selected>-- Please Select --</option>
               <option>City Campus</option>
               <option>MFI</option>
               <option>BMI</option>
               <option>MSI</option>
               <option>MIAT</option>
               <option>MICET</option>
               <option>MIMET</option>
               <option>RCMP</option>
             </select>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to finish writing your question.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get your question fully but I assume you want the vehicle facility to be selected after form is submitted, you put javascript to use for that:

```
          <select name="faculty" id="faculty">
           <option value="" selected>-- Please Select --</option>
           <option>City Campus</option>
           <option>MFI</option>
           <option>BMI</option>
           <option>MSI</option>
           <option>MIAT</option>
           <option>MICET</option>
           <option>MIMET</option>
           <option>RCMP</option>
         </select>

         <script type="text/javascripot">
          document.getElementById("faculty").value = "<?php echo $_POST['faculty']?>";
         </script>
```

However, if you meant how to show facilities coming from database, then you can go like this:

```
<select name="faculty" id="faculty">
<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo '<option value="'.$row['field_name'].'">'.$row['field_name'].'</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: ok...the vehicle_record hold all the vehicle detail by all faculty. let say user want to view all the vehicle that use by city campus faculty. how can i show listing that the vehicle are used in city campus faculty only

Comment: you should specify this in your sql query using WHERE clause like "SELECT * FROM vehicle_record where campus = 'name-here'"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have 2 select one for faculty and one for vehicle

```
<select name="faculty" id="faculty" onchange="getVehicles()">
....
</select>


<select name="vehicle" id="vehicle">
</select>
```

Javascript Code

```
function getVechiles()
{                                       
   $.getJSON("getVechiles.php",{faculty: $("select#faculty").val()}, function(j){
   if(j.length>0)
   {

        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option class="' + j[i].langClass + '" value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
        }
        $("#vechile").html(options);

    }

    });
}
```

and getVechiles.php

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $js="{value:".row['id'].",text:\"".$row["field"]."\"}";
      $rjson[] =  $js;

    }

   if(is_array($rjson))
   {
     echo '[' . implode(',', $rjson) . ']';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$i_faculty = $_POST['ifaculty'];
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("unable to connect");

mysql_select_db('fyp',$db) or die ("able to select");
$sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle_record WHERE faculty ='".$i_faculty."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query failed!");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $count = $count + 1;
    ?>
    <select name="ifaculty">
       <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Faculty --</option>
       <option>City Campus</option>
       <option>MFI</option>
       <option>BMI</option>
       <option>MSI</option>
       <option>MIAT</option>
       <option>MICET</option>
       <option>MIMET</option>
       <option>RCMP</option>
    </select>
```